# How can I “reset” or “restart” the Windows 10 Simplified Chinese IME when the 英/中 stops responding?

Tags: windows-10, notification-area, chinese, ime

In Windows 10's Chinese IMEs there is a clickable icon in the lower right of the screen between the touch keyboard icon and the keyboard layout icon that displays 英 when you're in English input mode and 中 when you're in Chinese input mode.

[image: The icon]

To switch between modes you either click this icon or click the shift key.

After hibernating my laptop overnight these two have ceased to work but I'm working on several things and don't really want to reboot right now.

- Any amount of switching between other keyboard layouts and IMEs has no effect.
- Right clicking the icon has no effect

Is there a way to restart a driver, service, etc, that will "reset" the Chinese IME without disturbing the state of my running apps?

Answer (score 2):

For **restarting** it, you can just open your task manager, force stop `ChsIME.exe`, and try toggle IME from the system tray. It will restart again and all your running app is not affected.